# "EOF occurred in violation of protocol" using requests on wonky server

Tags: python-2.7, openssl, python-requests

## The problem

I need to connect to a server running an outdated configuration using the Python `requests` package. Here's [the report from SSL Labs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=public.cdpehs.com&hideResults=on) on the server configuration. Despite trying just about every solution that I've read on StackOverflow, GitHub issues, and @Lukasa's own blog, I'm still coming up with the following error:

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='public.cdpehs.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /ILENVPBL/ESTABLISHMENT/ShowESTABLISHMENTTablePage.aspx?ESTTST_CTY=asgGk3ztR6c%3D (Caused by SSLError(SSLEOFError(8, u'EOF occurred in violation of protocol (_ssl.c:590)'),))
```

## What I've tried

Based on the existing answers, I've tried

- Installing `requests[security]`, `idna`, `pyopenssl`, `pyasn1`, and `ndg-httpsclient` via `pip`
- Changing the `ssl_version` of the `PoolManager` in a mounted custom adapter
- Changing the cipher suites of the `ssl_context` of the `PoolManager` in a mounted custom adapter

Here's the most recent version of my test script:

```
import requests
import ssl
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_ import create_urllib3_context
from urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter

class DESAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False, *args, **kwargs):
        CIPHERS = (
            'ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+HIGH:'
            'DH+HIGH:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+HIGH:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:'
            '!eNULL:!MD5:DES-CBC3-SHA'
        )
        context = create_urllib3_context(ciphers=CIPHERS)  # also tried 'ALL'
        kwargs['ssl_context'] = context
        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections, 
            maxsize=maxsize, 
            block=block, 
            ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1, 
            *args, 
            **kwargs
        )

sess = requests.Session()
sess.mount('https://', DESAdapter())
res = sess.get('https://public.cdpehs.com/ILENVPBL/ESTABLISHMENT/ShowESTABLISHMENTTablePage.aspx?ESTTST_CTY=asgGk3ztR6c%3D')
```

## Diagnostic info

If I'm reading the SSL Labs report (linked above) correctly, this server is only configured for TLSv1 / `TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA`. This cipher suite corresponds with `DES-CBC3-SHA` [according to OpenSSL docs](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/apps/ciphers.html). Under the "Handshake Simulation" section of the report, I note that the OpenSSL 1.0.x results are listed as "Server closed connection", which seems concerning.

OpenSSL details:

```
$ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2g-fips  1 Mar 2016

$ openssl ciphers -v | grep DES | sort | head -5
DES-CBC3-SHA            SSLv3 Kx=RSA      Au=RSA  Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
DH-DSS-DES-CBC3-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH/DSS   Au=DH   Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
DH-RSA-DES-CBC3-SHA     SSLv3 Kx=DH/RSA   Au=DH   Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDH-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH/ECDSA Au=ECDH Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
ECDHE-ECDSA-DES-CBC3-SHA SSLv3 Kx=ECDH     Au=ECDSA Enc=3DES(168) Mac=SHA1
```

Python details:

```
$ python --version
Python 2.7.12

$ pip list
asn1crypto (0.24.0)
backports.ssl-match-hostname (3.5.0.1)
cached-property (1.4.2)
certifi (2018.4.16)
cffi (1.11.5)
chardet (3.0.4)
crcmod (1.7)
cryptography (2.2.2)
docker (3.3.0)
docker-compose (1.21.2)
docker-pycreds (0.2.3)
dockerpty (0.4.1)
docopt (0.6.2)
enum34 (1.1.6)
functools32 (3.2.3.post2)
idna (2.7)
ipaddress (1.0.22)
jsonschema (2.6.0)
ndg-httpsclient (0.5.0)
pip (8.1.2)
psycopg2 (2.7.4)
pyasn1 (0.4.3)
pycparser (2.18)
pyOpenSSL (18.0.0)
python-apt (1.1.0b1)
PyYAML (3.12)
requests (2.19.0)
setuptools (20.7.0)
six (1.11.0)
texttable (0.9.1)
urllib3 (1.23)
websocket-client (0.47.0)
wheel (0.29.0)
```

Solutions that entail upgraded packages are feasible, but I'd prefer not to upgrade unless there's a high likelihood of success.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the custom HTTPAdapter subclass that you've created, I made a small modification that appears to work:

```
import ssl

import requests
from requests.adapters import HTTPAdapter
from requests.packages.urllib3.util.ssl_ import create_urllib3_context
from requests.packages.urllib3.poolmanager import PoolManager


class DESAdapter(HTTPAdapter):
    def init_poolmanager(self, connections, maxsize, block=False, *args, **kwargs):
        CIPHERS = (
            'ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+HIGH:'
            'DH+HIGH:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+HIGH:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:'
            '!eNULL:!MD5:DES-CBC3-SHA'
        )

        context = create_urllib3_context(ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)
        context.set_ciphers(CIPHERS)

        self.poolmanager = PoolManager(
            num_pools=connections,
            maxsize=maxsize,
            block=block,
            ssl_context=context,
            *args,
            **kwargs
        )

sess = requests.Session()
sess.mount('https://', DESAdapter())
res = sess.get('https://public.cdpehs.com/ILENVPBL/ESTABLISHMENT/ShowESTABLISHMENTTablePage.aspx?ESTTST_CTY=asgGk3ztR6c%3D')
print res
```

When calling `ssl_.create_urllib3_context`, you can pass in the protocol you want to use. In this case we want TLSv1: `ssl_.create_urllib3_context(ssl_version=ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1)`

It may be that the `ssl_version` and `ssl_context` cannot be used at the same time in the `PoolManager` constructor. It seems like `ssl_version` has precedence, so if it is set, then it causes `ssl_context` to be ignored. So make sure you remove `ssl_version` from the `PoolManager` constructor.

---

I noticed that you have PyOpenSSL installed.

The DESAdapter code I posted does not appear to work if you have PyOpenSSL installed. I'm not sure why that is though.

I do know that `requests` will use pyOpenSSL if it is installed. Otherwise `requests` will rely on the standard `ssl` module in python. I believe one reason to use pyOpenSSL was for SNI support in 2.7. But I believe SNI support is available in 2.7.12.